# Typo3 9.5 backend locked after changing password in phpmyadmin

Tags: typo3

My Hoster installed Typo3 9.5 for me with composer. I did the setup of typo3 but went on holidays a week afterwards and could not remind the password. So I changed the password in phpmyadmin but still can’t login. It says: Oops, an error occurred. I tried to find out the error and it told me that there must be a problem with the password hashing. I can't find the problem because the php version 7.3. has the correct hashing activated automatically in my opinion.

I can't use the front end login and no install tool can be activated with the ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL command. So I can’t work and tried to find a solution for two days now. My hoster won’t help with that problem.

Is there anyone who maybe had the same problem? I had to admit that I’m not a developer with much experience... Thanks a lot if anybody could give me an advice!

Comment: You need the install tool. Then type in there your new password and you get the value to put in the typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php

Comment: That’s what I wanted to do but I can't activate the install toll as well. I tried it with the command above but it did not function...

Comment: ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL is not a command. It's a empty file placed in typo3conf/ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL . Then call domain.tld/typo3/install

Comment: Yes, a file, correct. I did that but it didn’t help. Same output: the install toll is locked. Need to create that file. Yes, but that’s what I did.

Comment: You were right! The file wasn’t loaded correctly. I changed the name of a another file I uploaded and then could enter the install tool. Thanks a lot! Now I’m happy and can work...:-)

Comment: A write it as an answer. I would be nice if you accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create an (empty) file named `ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` in `typo3conf/` with permission that webserver at least can read it.
Then call `domain.tld/typo3/install`.
Try a password and save the returned hash in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`.

When you are logged in in the install tool, you can create a new admin user for TYPO3 backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you have forgotten the Install tool password, you can reset it by modifying **[your_site]/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php** on the Typo3 server. Replace the `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['installToolPassword']` row with the following:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['installToolPassword'] = 'bacb98acf97e0b6112b1d1b650b84971';
```

This will give you the default password ("**joh316**") back again.

[More information](https://wiki.typo3.org/FAQ/Reset_admin_password#Reset_Install_tool_password)

Greetings